# how pass php string variable to another page

Tags: php, variables

i want to transfer $cname through link to another page `test.php`

```
$cname = "Sai Ram Textiles";  
echo $link= "test.php?name=".$cname;  
echo '<a href='.$link.'>'."CLICK";
```

echo result is ok , which is
`test.php?name=Sai Ram Textiles`

but when i click it, result is
`test.php?name=Sai`

but it should be
`test.php?name=Sai+Ram+Textiles`

What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode):

```
$link = "test.php?name=" . urlencode($cname);
```

Comment: thanks rid, urlencode works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [htmlurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

It transforms the spaces,or any other illegal characters for that matter, into the corresponding encoded value.